How to run only part of the code in CoLab
I'm currently working on an image recognition project, and the pre-processing steps before the model execution take a considerable amount of time. When an error occurs in the model, I have to re-run everything from the beginning, which is very time-consuming. Is there a way to avoid running the entire process from scratch and only execute the model part?
If the code is not executed from the beginning, the package installation and labeling parts in the initial sections do not run properly.

any specifics? you're being exceedingly vague. [tour], [ask], [mre]
